# Parsing error when trying to add class via state to list item element

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React app and I am using the hooks useState and useCallback to control navigation between pages.

That part works, but I want to highlight the current page link.

So added a new state element called 'chosen' that is set with 'setChosen'.

```
const [chosen, setChosen] = useState();
const [showGameViewer, setGamerViewer] = useState(false);
const [showGameCreator, setGameCreator] = useState(false);
```

Then in my useCallback, I use setChosen:

```
const handleLinkMenuClick = useCallback(e => { setGamerViewer(false) || (setGameCreator(true) && setChosen(true))});
```

My links look like this, I am trying to append the CSS class called "current" to the className:

```
<li className="nav-item " {chosen && "current"}>
    <a className="nav-link" href="#" onClick={handleLinkMenuClick}>Show Game Creator</a>
</li>
```

And my css:

```
.chosen {
    background: yellow;
}
```

But I am getting an error for the above code {chosen && "current"} that says:

```
const chosen is undefined. Parsing Error: Unexpected token
```

I'm not sure why it's saying that.  I have 'chosen' defined above.  So it should know.

Does anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: ```setGamerViewer(false)``` returns always true and the rest of the code does not execute, so chosen will always be undefined.
Also, you are trying to add something to className but it's not inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render it conditionally

```
<li className={`nav-item ${chosen ? 'current' : ''}`}>
    <a className="nav-link" href="#" onClick={handleLinkMenuClick}>Show Game Creator</a>
</li>
```

And I think you want to add current CSS,so you should write it as

```
.current {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: react uses jsx,we are using chosen variable inside `` if we don't declare it using $ then it will consider it as a string

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error, but I am seeing no changes to a chosen link.  In fact, I don't think the 'chosen' state variable is getting set now for some reason.

Comment: You are setting only gameViewer,the code after || is not setting stateconst handleLinkMenuClick = useCallback(e => { setGamerViewer(false) || (setGameCreator(true) && setChosen(true))});

Comment: But setChosen sets chosen to true

Comment: Instead of writing it as useCallback you can write it as arrow function                                     const handleLinkMenuClick =(e)=> { setGamerViewer(false) || (setGameCreator(true) && setChosen(true))};